# How to disable header " X-Frame-Options: deny "?

Tags: django, heroku, x-frame-options

I created a [website](https://gkwhelps.herokuapp.com) in `Django` that I deployed on `heroku`. I am trying to display this website from an html page using an iframe. However, when I load my html page, I get the error: **gkwhelps.herokuapp.com refused the connection.** And when inspecting the page I get the following message:`Refused to display 'http://gkwhelps.herokuapp.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.` To solve this problem, I modified my `settings.py` like this:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

     ...

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.clickjacking import xframe_options_exempt

@xframe_options_exempt
def ok_to_load_in_a_frame(request):
    return HttpResponse("This page is safe to load in a frame on any site.")
```

and I updated my site. But despite this, I still get the same error when I reload my page. I don't know why yet I updated my site.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following for setting same origin xframe option

```
from django.views.decorators.clickjacking import xframe_options_sameorigin

@xframe_options_sameorigin
def ok_to_load_in_a_frame(request):
    return HttpResponse("This page is safe to load in a frame on any site.")
```

If you want to set it for your whole app, you could try adding the below line in your settings.py file

```
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
```